# Is it necessary to explicitly Invoke calls to COM object's thread?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, activex, rcw

I am using a 3rd party Activex control from .NET. I have successfully created the RCWs (AxInterop.ACMELib.dll and Interop.ACMELib.dll) by adding a reference to the ActiveX ocx and dragging a control onto my form.

At this point, the interface that the RCW provides is lacking and I've decided to create my own Component as an additional wrapper. One reason is that I access the RCW from many threads and I wanted to synchronize access to the RCW to only one thread at a time. My class looks like:

```
Public Class ACMEWrapper ' my Component
    Inherits AxACMELib.ACMEClass 

    Public Overrides Function GetData() As Int()
        Dim result As Int()
        Try
            SyncLock LockACMEObject
                result = MyBase.GetData()
            End SyncLock
            Return result
        Catch
            ' log exception, etc.
        End Try
    End Function
```

This class works fine in most cases. However, there are times when my application crashes with no Exception that can be handled by my application. Not even from a catch-all unhandled exception handler. In some cases it does actually catch an "External component has thrown an exception..." from which I cannot recover.

I thought i had tried everything until on a whim I explicitly Invoked all calls to the RCW on the thread it was created on i.e.

```
MyBase.Invoke(Sub() result = MyBase.GetData())
```

My application no longer crashes in this manner. I've searched the web for a justification for my actions as when something works I want to know *why* it worked. Finding nothing, I decided to post this question. Can someone tell me why what I did is working, and guide me to some literature with more information on this subject?

Comment: Hmm, this is unusual, ActiveX controls are never thread-safe.  You'll need to document the ThreadingModel registry key for the component.  Having trouble when it is wrong (like Both or Free) is expected, your SyncLock doesn't help solve that.  Your Invoke() call does.

Comment: Then calls are already marshaled automatically without having to call Invoke().  Nor is locking necessary.  You'd best take a good hard look at your wrapper methods and make sure they don't cause threading trouble.

Comment: I only locked every call to the base component because I assumed it wasn't handling concurrent calls properly when i was getting memory leaks and random crashes. The 3rd party has admitted experiencing memory leaks when they use it in c++ but they don't know how to fix it. The locking definitely solved a problem there and I get considerably less crashes from "external component" and no more memory leaks. Remember...? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16948780/how-to-debug-exception-not-handled-by-clr

Comment: I thought the calls were supposed to be marshaled automatically as well, as you said. I'm still unsure why the `MyBase.Invoke()` has stopped the crashing.

Comment: Just changing timing is enough to hide threading race bugs, Invoke() certainly does that.  Clearly you do need to worry about this.

Comment: I understand what you're saying. But doesn't the fact that the exception is coming from external code rule that out since I am synchronizing access to it?

Comment: Anyway, do you know of a good guide for properly working with ActiveX from .NET?